# Adding filter to a for a query of groups a user belongs in bugzilla

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

```
select
  profiles.realname as User_Name,
  sum(ba.added) as Hours_Worked
from
  bugs_activity ba join user_group_map u on ba.who = u.user_id
  join profiles on ba.who = profiles.userid
where
  u.group_id = '15' and
  ba.fieldid = '47' and
  YEARweek(ba.bug_when) = YEARweek(CURRENT_DATE)
group by ba.who;
```

This query now can find the time for users in a group.

I have learned lot on this site from other users posts, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my original question with the script, with the script I figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the schema in question, or how you really want to filter, the best I can do is point you at some info on how to use JOINs:

[SQL Joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Yes a JOIN is what I wanted to do.  Now Just learning how to code it in mysql now.  Just want to get the time of the users in users1 group.